# Call gazebo/set_model_state without resetting position

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone. I'm currently trying to use gazebo/set_model_state in a C++ program to set a robot's velocity. My preliminary code is below:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <gazebo_msgs/SetModelState.h>
#include <cstdlib>
//I'm going to implement user-specified twist values later.
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc,argv,"robot_mover_mark_two");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<gazebo_msgs::SetModelState>("/gazebo/set_model_state");
  gazebo_msgs::SetModelState setmodelstate;
  gazebo_msgs::ModelState modelstate;
  modelstate.model_name = "my_robot";
  modelstate.reference_frame = "world";

  geometry_msgs::Twist model_twist;
  model_twist.linear.x = 1.0;
  model_twist.linear.y = 1.0;
  model_twist.linear.z = 0.0;
  model_twist.angular.x = 0.25;
  model_twist.angular.y = 0.0;
  model_twist.angular.z = 0.0;
  modelstate.twist = model_twist;

  setmodelstate.request.model_state = modelstate;

  if (client.call(setmodelstate))
  {
    ROS_INFO("BRILLIANT!!!");
    ROS_INFO("%f, %f",modelstate.pose.position.x,modelstate.pose.position.y);
  }  
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service ");
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;  
}
```

I noticed that every time I run the command, the robot's position is reset to the origin in the Gazebo simulation environment. Are the position parameters set to zero by default if I don't include them in the rosservice call? If so, are there any ways I can use this code and have the model stay in the current position?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/180066/call-gazebo/set_model_state-without-resetting-position/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Under fuerte, I ha the same problem, I diactivate the gravity from e GUI and used the follwing code:

```
ros::ServiceClient client = node_handle_.serviceClient<gazebo_msgs::SetModelState>("/gazebo/set_model_state"); 
 geometry_msgs::Pose start_pose;
start_pose.position.x = currPosel.x+0.01;
start_pose.position.y = currPosel.x+0.01;
start_pose.position.z = 1.0;
start_pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
start_pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
start_pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
start_pose.orientation.w = 0.0;

geometry_msgs::Twist start_twist;
start_twist.linear.x = 1.1;
start_twist.linear.y = 0;
start_twist.linear.z = 0;
start_twist.angular.x = 0.0;
start_twist.angular.y = 0.0;
start_twist.angular.z = 0.0;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
gazebo_msgs::SetModelState setmodelstate;
gazebo_msgs::ModelState modelstate;
modelstate.model_name = "my_object"; 
modelstate.reference_frame = "world";
modelstate.twist = start_twist;
modelstate.pose = start_pose;
setmodelstate.request.model_state = modelstate;
if (client.call(setmodelstate))
{
  ROS_INFO("BRILLIANT!!!");
  ROS_INFO("%f, %f",modelstate.pose.position.x,modelstate.pose.position.y);
}
else
{
  ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service ");
  return 1;
}
return 0;
```

---

Originally posted by [jacobsolid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1909/jacobsolid/) with karma: 61 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1